# GCC 4.6.2 installation on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gcc

I am currently working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and would like to install GCC 4.6.2 so I can compile cd-hit-v4.5.7-2011-12-16.

I have a zipped version of GCC from#Download from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.2/

I have extracted the file using `tar -xzf .tar.gz`

I navigate to the extracted file  and use the following commands

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure
make
```

The compilation of GCC starts but renders this error:

```
In file included from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:87:0,
                 from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:36: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [Makefile:377: _muldi3.o] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgcc'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1007: multi-do] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:110: all-multi] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:18509: all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:23788: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2'
make: *** [Makefile:899: all] Error 2
```

I then tried to change that by:

```
sed -i 's@\./fixinc\.sh@-c true@' gcc/Makefile.in
cd /Desktop/RETROCLONE/RETROCLONE_BCR_PROCESSING_PIPELILNE/gcc-4.6.2
sed -i 's@\./fixinc\.sh@-c true@' gcc/Makefile.in
    cd ../gcc-build/
   ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=/usr \
    >     --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared \
    >     --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit \
    >     --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    >     --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --with-system-zlib
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether ln works... yes
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for mawk... mawk
    configure: error: building out of tree but ../gcc-4.6.2 contains host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.
    Use a pristine source tree when building in a separate tree
```

Comment: Very probably, you can compile cd-hit-v4.5.7-2011-12-16 with [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) which is part of  Ubuntu 20.04.1. Try that first